# Restricting User With Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 types of institutions in my system which are as follows

1. Crondale (Our inner system)
2. Kitchens
3. Institutions

I have multiple roles on each institution. So for example, a Kitchen can have

- Admin
- Cook
- etc

My first question is how should I restrict the user who belongs to Institution to view kitchen? I have multiple views in Kitchen so what should be done in order to restrict user going in any of them? Maybe something like [Authorize]? Any tutorial on how to do that? Any example links?

My second question is how should I restrict the Kitchen cook to view the Kitchen Admin screens? I would like to restrict the Controller actions as well as in my view I would like to hide some portions dependent upon the user roles?

Answer (score 0):

First you should Create Role for Each Users and at Beginning of user creation.

By using the below code

```
 Roles.CreateRole(userRole);
 Roles.AddUserToRole(UserName, userRole);
```

above code is default code used to add role and add the user to the specific role which is already added.

Note you have to done it on the registration time, not in the log-in time

And the role restriction can be made by applying the role on the top of each action method like given below.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
 public ActionResult method1()
  {

        return View("View1");
   }

 [Authorize(Roles = "Cook")]
 public ActionResult method2()
 {

        return View("View2");
}
```

By this those user with the role only able to access the Action method with the related Role.